# Git bash says branch is ((unknown))

Tags: git, repository, recover

I was just using Drupal's commandline tool Drush to test a core update on a local copy of my site.  It's unclear whether the update was a success, but it does look like it clobbered my git repo.  I'm using GitBash on a WAMP stack and it looks like this:

```
myuser@my-computer /c/wamp/www (d7upgrade)
$ drush pm-upgrade drupal
<.. whole bunch of drush output ..>

myuser@my-computer /c/wamp/www ((unknown))
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

However, I can see the `.git` directory in /c/wamp/www.  It isn't empty, in fact `.git\refs\heads` contains files named `master` and `d7upgrade` (my most current branch).

Can I recover my Git repo?

Comment: Do you have a `.git/HEAD` file? If that was deleted that can cause your symptoms.

Comment: You may find what you need with `git reflog`, although I do not understand what happened here.

Comment: Do you have a `GIT_DIR` or  `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable defined in your gitbash session?

Comment: @KevinBallard - sure enough, I've lost my HEAD.  Is there any way to recreate this? I wonder what else was scrubbed..

Comment: @doub1ejack: `echo 'ref: refs/heads/master' > .git/HEAD` should do it